# How Create radial Gradiant In Android like this

Tags: android, radial-gradients, android-shape

I want to Create a Gradient like this but :

[image]

left gradiant is my goal gradiant right gradiant is my gradiant
this is my gradiant code xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" >
<gradient
    android:centerColor="#ffffff"
    android:endColor="#4f4f4f"
    android:gradientRadius="700"
    android:startColor="#ffffff"
    android:type="radial" >
</gradient>
```

please help to create a gradient like left picture thx

Edited :
in real Device My gradiant show white .
Edit2 :
These Gradiant My Friend Post Ok but color in goal gradiant Not show in real device 
no Alternative Ways ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this :

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle" >
       <gradient
            android:centerColor="#E7E6E6"
            android:endColor="#DADADA"
            android:gradientRadius="800"
            android:startColor="#EEEDED"
            android:type="radial" >
       </gradient>
   </shape>
```

**Screenshot :**

[image]

Comment: good but please caution to center of gradiant : start picture center picture end picture yor gradiant is fine but not same end of your gradiant is not same start your gradiant

Comment: @zobydehkarimi check now

Comment: thx but center of your new gradiand is show circular ... but my goal is circular but smooth and fade thx

Comment: @zobydehkarimi  UPDATED AGAIN :  I have made like that kindly check again and when you make design on it then it wll not show in circular may be this time it is showing smooth.

Comment: thats better and fine ... please use color in my goal picture ... thxxx...please darker corner . thank you

Comment: I have mentioned the colors with these colors we can make this and I did this thing manually not with the help of tool. So please use this color. If this answer is helpful please accept and vote up the answer. @zobydehkarimi

Comment: in real phone Android 8.1 I see only white screen ...test on real device but all devices show white screen i can not see gradiant at all

Comment: <gradient
        android:centerColor="#E7E6E6"
        android:endColor="#DADADA"
        android:gradientRadius="800"
        android:startColor="#EEEDED"
        android:type="radial" >
    </gradient>

@zobydehkarimi

Comment: I can not see gradiant I see only White Screen .

Comment: @zobydehkarimi I have changed colors tooo.

Comment: I used updated color but see only white screen gradiant not show i set this gradiant to background RelativeLayout of my main activity but show only white screen

Comment: have you implemented android:background="@drawable/gradient"
into the parent layout @zobydehkarimi

Comment: yes i used this :  android:background="@drawable/maingradiant" please test with real device .. only show white screen

Comment: in my xml file it is showing correctly @zobydehkarimi

Comment: in android studio is ok but when running on real device show only white screen twho device test note 8 and galaxy j5 pro but only show white screen

Comment: @zobydehkarimi check this : http://prntscr.com/mzx6q7 
device : oneplus6T

Comment: center of gradiant is circular show ... but my goal is flat and smooth not show circular ...

Comment: http://prntscr.com/mzxf61 check this one @zobydehkarimi
 and this one is not showing circular and sorry to say now i am done with this

Comment: How darker corner ? I select darker gray but all gradiant is currepted and not match with gola gradiant . Please help last time . Please match darker color together .

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tool using this you can design any drawable [Tool](http://angrytools.com/gradient/)

try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
    <gradient
        android:type="linear"
        android:startColor="#FF2d7706"
        android:endColor="#FF98d434"
        android:angle="90"/>
</shape>
```

[image]

Comment: your gradiant is fine but not same please repeat start color at end of gradiant thx